# How to properly store minified JSON in git repository

Tags: json, git, minify, data-conversion, gitattributes

I want to store minified JSON `{"name":"JSON.minify()","type":"javascript"}` in git repository as following. I want `git show`, `git diff` and web view like GitHub\Gitlab\Bitbucket to consider this file as beautified JSON:

```json
{
   "name": "JSON.minify()",
   "type": "javascript" 
}
```

I want to see per-line changes and etc, but I want to have actual minified JSON when I perform `git clone`.

I want similar behavior as one with encoding case when [working-tree-encoding](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_working_tree_encoding) sat up.

Comment: This is not possible. May I ask why you want/need to store the file minified in the first place? You usually store files in their raw (developer friendly) form in Git and minification is part of the packaging/build process.

Comment: Although there *are* ways to do what you ask, I agree with @GaelJ's comment starting from the second sentence. Do you have a specific technical point, for which you need that file in a minfied version ?

Comment: @LeGEC Now that you say there are ways to do it, I'm curious to learn about it :)

Comment: one way to do this : you can store the minified version of the file in your repo, and name a diff driver in `.gitattributes` ([doc here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_diff)) for this file, which formats the content before comparison.

Comment: @GaelJ: However, if the OP's intention is only to store a minified version to "save space" with a smaller file, since the file is actually compressed before being stored in git, it doesn't really help. Or, as you said, if he needs the minified version for some specific purpose (for the deployment phase for example), the packaging/build process is the perfect place to do that.

Comment: hmm, I misread the part "Github/Gitlab/Bitbucket". What I mention would work locally, I don't know of a universal way to to have those hosting platforms do it.

Comment: @GaëlJ, In case of my project I export minified JSON (among other files) form external system. So I don't actually control what representation of code do I have. But I want to have it in original form and want to track changes in it.

Comment: @LeGEC, thanks for advice! But my main intention is to have that file readable representation at GitHub/Bitbucket/Gitlab. I'll check whether they support `diff` in `.gitattributes`

Comment: @petRUShka: ok, then I would follow GaelJ's advice : store the formatted version in your repo